# pthread offer no performance increase when using virtual cores

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads

I am playing around with pthreads for the first time and have noticed something strange when running on my machine.

I have an Intel i5 with 2 physical cores and 4 virtual cores.

When running my program with 2 threads, I get roughly double the performance, yet when running with 4 threads, I get the same performance as two threads. Why is this the case?

Results with 2 threads:
real    0m9.335s
user    0m18.233s
sys 0m0.132s

Results with 4 threads:
real    0m9.427s
user    0m34.130s
sys 0m0.180s

Edit: The code is fully parallelizable and the threads are running independently without any shared resources.

Comment: Tricky to say without knowing what your code actually does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This old article from when HyperThreading (HT) was first introduced provides a lot of details on how it works (though I'm sure many improvements have been made over the last 10 years). http://www.intel.com/technology/itj/2002/volume06issue01/vol6iss1_hyper_threading_technology.pdf:

> Each logical processor maintains a complete set of the architecture state. The architecture state consists of registers including the general-purpose registers, the control registers, the advanced programmable interrupt controller (APIC) registers, and some machine state registers. From a software perspective, once the architecture state is duplicated, the processor appears to be two processors. The number of transistors to store the architecture state is an extremely small fraction of the total.

However, the following sentence shows where HT can bottleneck:

> Logical processors share nearly all other resources on the physical processor, such as caches, execution units, branch predictors, control logic, and buses.

If the threads execution are each keeping one or more of those shared resources (such as the execution unit or buses) 100% busy, then the hyperthreading will not improve throughput.  Since benchmarks often exercise one aspect of a system (intentionally or not), it's not surprising that one of these shared processor resources would end up being a bottleneck and prevent HT from showing a benefit.

Answer (score 2):

Because you only really have 2 cores. [Hyper-threading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading) will not magically create 2 more cores for you. Hyper-threading makes it possible to run 4 threads on the CPU but not simultaneously. It will still allocate the threads on the two physical cores and switch the threads back and forth in the execution pipeline.

The performance increase you may expect is at BEST 30%.

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that hyperthreading is basically a way of reusing spare execution units on the CPU for a separate thread of execution. You're still working with the horsepower of two cores, it's just split four ways.

If your code is optimized such that it fully utilizes most of the available EUs, there's no spare resources left once it's running on both physical cores, so the hyperthreaded cores can't do any better.

Answer (score 1):

The performance gain when using multiple threads is very difficult to determine. Hyperthreading is also "less than one extra core" in performance for sure.

Besides from that, you may run into memory throughput issues, or your code is contending over locks or some such now that you have more of them - even if your own code is lock-less doesn't mean that for example I/O or some functions you call are completely able to run in parallel - there are sometimes "hidden" shared resources.

But most likely, your processor just can't go any faster.